# .loc replaces all columns values not just the indexed column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My code looks like:

```
GDP = pd.read_excel("GDP_in.xls", skiprows=4)
GDP.loc[GDP['Country Name'] == 'Korea, Rep.'] = 'South Korea'
GDP.loc[GDP['Country Name'] == 'Iran, Islamic Rep.'] = 'Iran'
GDP.loc[GDP['Country Name'] == 'Hong Kong SAR, China'] = 'Hong Kong'
GDP = GDP.set_index(['Country Name'])
GDP = GDP.iloc[:, 49:59]
```

I was expecting that this would simply change the value for the column 'Country Name', but it is changing the values of all the columns. For instance all column in the row with 'Korea, Rep.' have been changed to the value 'South Korea' in columns 49-59.

The resulting df looks something like:

```
               2006         2007         2008
United States  1e12         2e12        2.2e12
Iran           Iran         Iran         Iran
Australia      5e10         4e10         3e10 
South Korea   South Korea  South Korea  South Korea
```

Comment: psst, another good use case for `replace` here

Comment: or even `s = s.map(dict).fillna(s)` if you find `replace` slow.

Comment: .replace worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to indicate which column you want to change or pandas will assume you want all columns. When using `.loc` you can pass it rows and columns. `.loc[row, col]` so just give it Country Name as an input.

```
GDP = pd.read_excel("GDP_in.xls", skiprows=4)
GDP.loc[GDP['Country Name'] == 'Korea, Rep.', 'Country Name'] = 'South Korea'
GDP.loc[GDP['Country Name'] == 'Iran, Islamic Rep.', 'Country Name'] = 'Iran'
GDP.loc[GDP['Country Name'] == 'Hong Kong SAR, China', 'Country Name'] = 'Hong Kong'
GDP = GDP.set_index(['Country Name'])
GDP = GDP.iloc[:, 49:59]
```

[This post](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) from the Pandas Documentation is long but can be helpful in times like this.

As mentioned by @COLDSPEED in his comment you could simply

```
df['Country Name'].replace(
                         ['Korea, Rep.', 'Iran, Islamic Rep.', 'Hong Kong SAR, China'], 
                         ['South Korea', 'Iran', 'Hong Kong'],
                         inplace = True)
```

Comment: Or just use inplace: df['Country Name'].replace(
                              ['Korea, Rep.', 'Iran, Islamic Rep.', 'Hong Kong SAR, China'], 
                              ['South Korea', 'Iran', 'Hong Kong'], inplace=True)